# How can I get this to work? (java homework)

Tags: java, if-statement

http://i.imgur.com/oPbHR6p.png

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner eWord = new Scanner(System.in);
    String English;
    String Translated;
    String one = "an";
    String two = "au";
    String three = "annnnnn";
    String four = "ow";
    String five = "o";
    String six = "annnnnn";
    String seven = "annnnnn";
    String eight = "annnnnn";
    String nine = "annnnnn";
    String ten = "u";
System.out.println("Welcome to the Swedish Chef Translator 3000");
System.out.println("Type a word to translate");
while(true){
    English = eWord.nextLine();
    if(English.contains("an")){
        Translated = English.replace(one, "un");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("au")){
        Translated = English.replace(two, "oo");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("annnnnn")){
        Translated = English.replace(three, "unnnnnn");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("ow")){
        Translated = English.replace(four, "oo");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("o")){
        Translated = English.replace(five, "u");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("o")){
        Translated = English.replace(six, "u");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("o")){
        Translated = English.replace(seven, "u");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("o")){
        Translated = English.replace(eight, "u");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("o")){
        Translated = English.replace(nine, "u");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }

    if(English.contains("u")){
        Translated = English.replace(ten, "oo");
        System.out.println(Translated);
    }
}
    }
}
```

I didn't do number 3,6,7,8, or 9 yet. I wrote it in the code, but I just haven't gotten to it yet because it is more complicated.
My issue is: when I enter the word AUTHOR it outputs this:
oothor
authur
author
author
author
author
aoothor

none if those results are correct. It is suppose to output OOTHUR. and it outputs multiple results. How do I make this work? I don't get it. I already tried adding break; to each if statement and that doesn't work. I also tried putting replaceAll instead of just replace.

Comment: Don't link to your homework as the link may eventually break making this question worthless. Instead put the relevant problem into the question. Also, just remove the numbers you didn't get to yet. There's no need to bother us with that information if it isn't part of your current problem.

Comment: Now is the perfect time to start learning to use a debugger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform one replacement at a time, because that won't work.

Example: Rules 5 (`O` → `U`) and 10 (`U` → `OO`) conflicts.
If you do rule 5 before rule 10, you'd get `TUMOR` → `TUMUR` → `TOOMOOR`.
If you do rule 10 before rule 5, you'd get `TUMOR` → `TOOMOR` → `TUUMUR`.
Correct answer is `TUMOR` → `TOOMUR`.

You have to traverse the list from left to right, and go through the 10 rules for each position, advancing the position by 2 for rules 1, 2, 4, and 7, and keeping special track of whether you already did rule 6.

As for the interpretation of rules 7, 8, and 9, I read them as "Replace an occurrence of ...", such that `EEL` → `IEL` (rule 9). Implementing them as "Replace repeating occurrences of ...", such that `EEL` → `IIL`, would be more complex. Coders choice, I guess.

---

Now, try some long words: ;-)

```
UNCHARACTERISTICALLY  →  OONCHERECTEREESTICELLY
UNITED ARAB EMIRATES  →  OONEETED EREB IMEERETES
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying I have to rearrange them?

Comment: Rearrange what? I was saying that you can't go through the rules in order, and for each rule scan the entire string. You have to scan the string, and for each position go through the rules.